# Dynamically construct resulting dataframe based on input in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a dynamic resulting dataframe based on various constant and nonconstant columns. Sometimes I can have 1 position thus requiring only one new row to be appended, other times it can be 2 or more positions.

Expected output is a dataframe with the following:

```
          status  position presence_check
0         Pass    10       Y
1         Pass    2        Y
2         Pass    3        Y
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#assume a position, a resulting series, that calculates positions and returns a series containing 10,2,3. The status and presence check are static data
#create dataframe
filtered_positions_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['status', 'position', 'presence_check'])

last_row = filtered_positions_df.iloc[-1]
new_row = {
'status': 'Pass',
'position': last_row.position_series,
'presence_check': 'Y',
}

filtered_positions_df = filtered_positions_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

However, when I attempt this I seem to get a "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error. Ultimately, regardless of what the position series generates (ie. 10,2,3 or just 2 or just 5) I want to create an output dataframe that has the static status and presence_check values alongside the dynamic position values.

Comment: What are the input data for your expected output?

Comment: `filtered_positions_df.iloc[-1]` does not work. `filtered_positions_df` is an empty DataFrame in your example. Also what is `last_row.position_series`? Your columns are "status", "position" and "presence_check". There is no "position_series"

Comment: apologies, position is the column name. The input is a series. @Corralien, the input data is a series that is generated through a propriety calculation that I cant share but we can assume its just a series with integers in them as described above